# PHP SQL Array not returning anything

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

Can I have some advice on where I'm going wrong with this Query?

```
 $entry_id = '1';
 $accident_road = $form_data[58]["id"]; //print_r returns "116"

        $accident_road_array = $wpdb->get_results(
          "SELECT id FROM wp_rg_lead_detail
           WHERE field_number = '$accident_road'
           AND 'lead_id' = '$entry_id' ",
           ARRAY_A); 


 print_r returns 'Array()'
```

Comment: Did you intend to name that first variable `$accident_road_exp`? That's what your query expects.

Comment: Yes, sorry that was an error on my part. see edited code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume lead_id is a field in DB so you don't need quotes for it:

```
AND lead_id = '$entry_id'
```

You're also going wrong by putting variables directly into the query, you make your app vulnerable to SQL injections. consider using prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

you set values in variable 
$accident_road 
while down there in query you used 
'$accident_road_exp' 
cross check this one man

Comment: please correct 
'lead_id' = '$entry_id' ", 
as  
`lead_id` = '$entry_id' ",